# Single pattern to match digits in a SMS message with 2 allowed formas

Tags: java, android, regex

I am extracting digits from a SMS where I want to extract only the digits in either one of these formats:

```
ID is xxx
For User: yyyy ID:xxxx
```

When I use `"\\d+"` it extracts the username (`yyyy`) instead of `xxxx`.

I also tried with the pattern `\d+ | [ID:]\d+` but it only works for the SMS with username, not for the first type.

Is there any way to write a regular expression where if this pattern is not matched, it checks for another pattern in Android?

Also, i tried with 2 different patterns with an if and elseif, but that also didn't work. For example:

```
public Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
public Pattern q=Pattern.compile("[ID:]\\d+");

if (msgbody.contains("ID"){
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(msgbody);
    final Matcher n = q.matcher(msgbody);
    if(m.find()){
        \\first pattern p matched.
    } else if(n.find()){
        \\Second Pattern q matched
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While it is perfectly possible to test as many regex matches as you want, both of your test cases match `\\d`. Then, you're not testing against the 2nd expression (which won't achieve what you want).

You can match both `ID is xxx` and `For User: xxxx ID:yyyy` with a single regex.

Use the following expression:

```
^(?:For User: \\S+ ID:|ID is )(\\d+)$
```

- `(?:` ... `|` ... `)` is a group with 2 alternatives

  - `For User: \\S+ ID:` matches the literal text for your second case, and with any username that does not contain spaces.
  - `ID is` matches your first case literally.
- `(\\d+)` matches a number, capturing the match (that we can later reference as `m.group[1]`.

#### Code

```
String msgbody = "ID is 12345"; //For testing purposes

Pattern idPatt = Pattern.compile("^(?:For User: \\S+ ID:|ID is )(\\d+)$");
Matcher m = idPatt.matcher(msgbody);

if (m.find()) {
    //Print the text matched by the first group (in parentheses)
    System.out.println("Matched: " + m.group(1));
} else {
    System.out.println("Invalid message body");
}
```

<kbd>[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/rUGYTr)</kbd>